# Can not get Spring OAuth SSO filter to trigger

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I have a spring boot + angular web app that closely follow the setup of this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/): I'm running Authorization Server, Resource Server, UI web app all in the same Spring Boot application.

Then I have the need to allow user to login with third party social login (facebook etc.) and implicitly create user accounts if use hasn't registered previously.

I was trying to accomplish that by following another tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).

In the tutorial, making a `GET /login/facebook` call would trigger the SSOFilter that was setup in the code. But that's not happening with my own code. I tried to change the order of the SSO filter to different numbers and it didn't help either.

In the logs from the tutorial auth-server example. I see the following output:

```
2016-09-24 22:59:26.728 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/login/facebook' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2016-09-24 22:59:26.728 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-24 22:59:26.729 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-24 22:59:26.729 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-09-24 22:59:26.729 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-09-24 22:59:26.731 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-24 22:59:26.732 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-09-24 22:59:26.736 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-24 22:59:26.736 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login/facebook' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-09-24 22:59:26.736 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CompositeFilter'
2016-09-24 22:59:26.737 DEBUG 59433 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login/facebook'; against '/login/facebook'
```

In my own logs, I don't see the `CompositeFilter` ever being triggered:

```
2016-09-24 23:38:54.545 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/login/facebook' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.546 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.547 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.547 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login/facebook'; against '/logout'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login/facebook' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login/facebook' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2016-09-24 23:38:54.548 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login/facebook' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.549 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.550 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.551 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.551 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.552 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.552 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.552 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login/facebook'; against '/api/**'
2016-09-24 23:38:54.552 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object - authentication not attempted
2016-09-24 23:38:54.553 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/facebook reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-09-24 23:38:54.571 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login/facebook
2016-09-24 23:38:54.571 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/login/facebook]
2016-09-24 23:38:54.574 DEBUG 60184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@76f064a2
```

I'm pulling my hair off yet still clueless what went wrong with my code.

Here's code snippets of my setup:

**main class file:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TuangouApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TuangouApplication.class, args);
    }

    // this is for WAR file deployment
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TuangouApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
       return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration file.**
Almost identical to the spring oauth2 tutorial `auth-server` example.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Order(6)
public class TuangouConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off   
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

//  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
    protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new DatabaseUserServiceDetails();
        }
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request
                        .getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null
                            || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        System.out.println("### foobar");
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ClientResources github() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
        filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        filter.setRestTemplate(template);
        filter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(
                client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId()));
        return filter;
    }
}

class ClientResources {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

**Authorization Server config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager auth;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
            throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .authenticationManager(auth).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
//          .withClient("grubmarket")
//              .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "client_credentials",
//                      "refresh_token", "implicit")
//              .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
//              .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
//              .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
//              .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

**Resource Server config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
//      http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/deals").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `@Order` for `org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourcererverConfiguration` is 3.

Your `TuangouConfiguration` is set with `@Order(6)`. So if you change it to `@Order(2)` the ssoFilter or `CompositeFilter` will get called when request is `GET /login/facebook`

Comment: That worked! Where can I find the default order for various filters? And is it possible to print out or log the relative order of all the filters when the program runs?

Comment: The default order for the spring security filter chain created by `@EnableResourceServer` is specified in the javadoc - ...hard-coded Order (of 3). Also, you can debug out the order of filters in their respective chain by overriding the following in your `TuangouConfiguration`....`public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.debug(true);
 }
`

Comment: Another important configuration to note is `HttpSecurity.antMatcher()`. I noticed you are using this in `TuangouConfiguration` and `ResourceServerConfiguration` but they both are matching on `/**`. I would recommend using a more specific pattern on `ResourceServerConfiguration`, for example, `/api/**`. This would also work and allow your `ssoFilter` to be called when the request is `/login/facebook` and would eliminate the need to use @Order on your `TuangouConfiguration`. I would highly recommend using this configuration approach.

Comment: Take a look at this example when configuring [Multiple HttpSecurity's](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)